# Is there a way in SQL that I can partition out different values in a column, into their own column by grouping them to a shared primary key?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am trying to execute a list of information in SQL Oracle where I can get a unique set of values on a select statement I am running. Here is an example of the query I am running with dummy placeholders:

```
    `select mt.key_nbr, sd.policy_nbr
     , sd.policy_type

     from main_table mt

     inner join middleman_table md on 
     mt.join_key = md.join_key

     inner join second_table sd on 
     md.second_join_key = sd.second_join_key`
```

The results that compute are

| **mt.key_nbr** | **sd.policy_nbr** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3-DOC |
| 1 | 5-HMC |
| 1 | 3-PLC |
| 2 | 4-DOC |
| 2 | 6-HMC |
| 2 | 7-PLC |

In order to compute a list that only gets the unique values of the primary key, but still displays all of the data on the same row, I would like to find a way to compute a select statement that displays a result looking like this:

| **mt.key_nbr** | **sd.policy_nbr1** | **sd.policy_nbr2** | **sd.policy_nbr3** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3-DOC | 5-HMC | 3-PLC |
| 2 | 4-DOC | 6-HMC | 7-PLC |

Is there an easy way to execute this output that I am just not seeing right now? I'm assuming it would have to do with adding a pivot clause or something similar to that, but I am still gaining my chops in advanced sql functions and am a bit confused as to how I can accomplish this.

I believe it is also worth mentioning that the sd.policy_nbr are also categorized by another column in the "second_table" table called "policy_type", where they are categorized by char values. ex:

| **mt.key_nbr** | **sd.policy_nbr** | **sd.policy_type** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3-DOC | "Traveler policy" |
| 1 | 5-HMC | "Driver policy" |
| 1 | 3-PLC | "Cyclist policy" |

I'm not sure if this column would provide any help but I thought it was worth mentioning. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like standard `pivot`

Comment: The `policy_type` information might be very useful. For one thing, instead of column names like `policy_nbr1` etc., names like `traveler`, `cyclist`, `driver` etc. would make much more sense. (And, you should want only one type of policy to be shown in each column - some people don't have a certain type of policy, the value should be `null`.) Moreover, knowing all the policy types in advance means you will know the number of output columns in advance - so you won't need dynamic pivoting, which is a pain in the derrière.

Answer (score 0):

Your three-column sample data don't reflect your two-column initial query - but ok, I'll work with your two column input, plus a sequence number - to preserve order as you need it.

Without using `PIVOT` - works with practically all DBMS-s -

try this:

```
WITH
outer_query(key_nbr,policy_nbr,seq) AS (
-- here , your select would go:
--  SELECT 
--    mt.key_nbr
--  , sd.policy_nbr
-- /* , sd.policy_type */ - this one would be replaced by a sequence ..
--
--  FROM main_table mt
--
--  INNER JOIN middleman_table md 
--   ON mt.join_key = md.join_key
--
--  inner join second_table sd 
--    ON md.second_join_key = sd.second_join_key
------------------------------------------------
-- but replace it with the data you provided, 
-- and add a sorting column within the key_nbr
-- to get the column order as you seem to need it - 
          SELECT 1,'3-DOC',1
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'5-HMC',2
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'3-PLC',3
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'4-DOC',1
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'6-HMC',2
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'7-PLC',3
)
SELECT
  key_nbr
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 1 THEN policy_nbr END) AS policy_nbr_1
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 2 THEN policy_nbr END) AS policy_nbr_2
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 3 THEN policy_nbr END) AS policy_nbr_3
FROM outer_query
GROUP BY 1;
 key_nbr | policy_nbr_1 | policy_nbr_2 | policy_nbr_3 
---------+--------------+--------------+--------------
       1 | 3-DOC        | 5-HMC        | 3-PLC
       2 | 4-DOC        | 6-HMC        | 7-PLC
```